# Searching vim history for matching first characters

Tags: vim

In bash, adding the lines

```
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward
```

to my .inputrc, allows me to search the history for expressions that begin with the characters in front of my cursor by using the `<page-up>`/`<page-down>` keys.

Can I achieve something similar in vim?

I already know about the possibility of opening a history window with `q:` and performing even complex searches there, but I am looking for a simple solution for the simplest case of history search.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is built-in as `<Up>` and `<Down>`.

Of course, you can customize this, e.g.:

```
:cnoremap <PageUp> <Up>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure how I could miss this.